# How to sum items from subtable in SQL

Tags: t-sql, math, join, sum, union

Let's say I have table `orders`

```
id      name
1       order1
2       order2
3       order3
```

and subtable `items`

```
id    parent   amount    price
1     1        1         10
2     1        3         20
3     2        2         5
4     2        5         1
```

I would like to create query with order with added column `value`. it should calculate order with all relevant items

```
id      name      value
1       order1    70
2       order2    15
3       order3    0
```

Is this possible with TSQL

Answer (score 2):

`GROUP BY` and `SUM` would do it, need to use `left join`  and `isnull` as you don't have items for all orders.

```
    SELECT o.id, o.name, isnull(sum(i.amount*i.price),0) as value
    FROM orders o
    left join items i
    on o.id = i.parent
    group by o.id, o.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this

```
SELECT o.name, i.Value FROM orders o WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT parent, SUM(price) AS Value FROM items WITH (NOLOCK) GROUP BY parent) i
ON o.id = i.parent
```

...seems like RADAR beat me to the answer.
EDIT: missing the ON line.